# DDS and Simulation Time

Tags: gazebo, ros2, simulation, dds, timestamp

I am using a the eProsima Micro-XRCE-DDS agent (https://github.com/eProsima/Micro-XRCE-DDS-Agent) to send messages between my ROS2 application and the PX4 Autopilot (https://github.com/PX4/PX4-Autopilot).

I have a problem with the messages timestamp when I work on the Gazebo simulator. In particular, all the of my nodes use the simulation time provided by Gazebo trough the `/clock` topic (i.e. I set the `use_sim_time` parameter to `true` on all the running nodes), while the Micro-XRCE-DDS Agent publishes the messages read from the Client with the SystemTime timestamps.

Is there a way to set up the Micro-XRCE-DDS Agent so that it publishes the messages using the simulation time too?

**P.S.**
For now, the only solution I came up with was to create an additional nodes that just subscribes to the topics I need to read from the DDS Client and republishes the messages on separate topics with the correct timestamps, but it seems to me an unnecessary additional step.

Answer (score 1):

As there is no answer for over 4 months I will provide some approaches:

- Is it required that `use_sim_time` is set to true? Why not using SystemTime as well?
- Otherwise why do you need the timestamps at all? As far as I know manual timestamps and doing time sync is no longer required for Micro-XRCE-DDS
- However the [migration quideline](https://docs.px4.io/main/en/middleware/uxrce_dds.html#fast-rtps-to-uxrce-dds-migration-guidelines) offers the following python command to sync timestamps: `msg.timestamp = int(self.get_clock().now().nanoseconds / 1000)`
- Additionally [UXRCE-DDS Client Parameter](https://docs.px4.io/main/en/advanced_config/parameter_reference.html#uxrce-dds-client) `UXRCE_DDS_SYNCT` might be interesting for you

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. To answer your questions: I needed the timestamp because I was using a time synchronizer to start a callback (it is a type of message filter). So, when reading topics from the the PX4 trough the MicroDDS bridge, I got timestamps that were not synchronized with the topics of my application and the callback could not be called.

Anyway, I am still using the additional node to read topics from the PX4 and "synchronize" them with the time stamps of the external computer whenever I need it.